# is there a way to parse sql files before they are executed in dbup using octopus deploy?

Tags: mstest, octopus-deploy, dbup

I use DbUp to deploy scripts. this is a part of a workflow that uses Octopus Deploy. we want to check if the scripts are valid before they are executed on a database. is there a way to do some sort of unit testing for DbUp or parse the sql files before they are executed? I checked the documentation but couldn't find any.

I want to check the SQL scripts to be validated for syntactical issues at least.

Comment: How are you executing the dbup migration? Is it during the application startup or in a separate process?
Dbup supports wrapping the upgrade in a [transaction](https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more-info/transactions/), which you could rollback in a dry-run mode.